# Keras LSTM predict two features from one input in Text classification?

Tags: python, keras, text-classification

I have X as text, with two different labels(columns) to train.

```
--input.csv--
content, category, rate
text test, 1, 3
new test, 2, 2
```

Here my input X will be content. I have converted it to sequence matrix. I need both category and rate to be trained along with content. I couldn't figure out how to pass this inside the layers.

```
def RNN():
    num_categories = 2
    num_rates = 3
    inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])

    layer = Embedding(max_words,150,input_length=max_len)(inputs)
    layer = LSTM(100)(layer)

    shared_layer = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='FC1')(layer)
    shared_layer = Dropout(0.5)(shared_layer)

    cat_out = Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax', name='cat_out')(shared_layer)
    rate_out = Dense(num_rates, activation='softmax', name='rate_out')(shared_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=[cat_out, rate_out])
    return model

model = RNN()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])  
model.fit(sequences_matrix,[Y_train, Z_train])
```

Y_train contains only category. I want to add rate to the training. Does any one know?
I want two results. One should be about category and another is Rate. 
Currently its returning only the label. Not with the rate. I don't know the way to add a layer for the Rate column.

Comment: Can you add the shape of your `sequences_matrix` and `Y_train`

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You talk about problems in your labels but post code for your model. The error you give concerns the input shape of your labels whose code is nowhere to be found. Think about what you want to have answered and edit your question. Based on what can be gained from your question, what stops you from putting both category and rate into your labels? If you have both as values in `np.array`s, a simple `np.concatenate` already does the trick.

Comment: ok. i will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with the functional API, just let the network have 2 outputs from the shared feature layer:

```
shared_layer = Dense(256, activation='relu', name='FC1')(layer)
shared_layer = Dropout(0.5)(shared_layer)
cat_out = Dense(num_categories, activation='softmax', name='cat_out')(shared_layer)
rate_out = Dense(num_rates, activation='softmax', name='rate_out')(shared_layer)

model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=[cat_out, rate_out])
return model
```

You will now train with two targets, `y_train_cat` and `y_train_rate` and give them as a list to `model.fit(X_train, [y_train_cat, y_train_rate])` and the model will make two distinct predictions.

Have a look at the functional API [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) on how to handle multi-input / multi-output models.

Comment: I think you have forgotten to pass the `shared_layer` to `rate_out` layer as well.

Comment: Layer is compiled successfully. Thanks...!
But one more issue.

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected cat_out to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)
--code---
le = LabelEncoder()
Y = le.fit_transform(Y)
Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)

@nuric

Comment: Why are you reshaping, your y targets should be 2D of shape `(samples, num_categories)` and `(samples, num_rates)` to be passed as a list into `fit` function.

Comment: Do you mean like this?
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(Y_train.shape[0], num_categories)
print(Y_train.shape)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 219 into shape (219,2) 
@nuric

Comment: Oh I see, you have sparse labels so just `[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, ...]` in that case you need compile your model with `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` so it automatically expands the label index into a one-hot vector.